# Django Forms: En-/Disable a Charfield dynamically

Tags: django, django-forms

i have a form with a ChoiceField and a CharField. Now i want to enable the CharField just when i select a specific choice of the ChoiceField (e.g. choice 3). Otherwise the CharField should be disabled.

My ChoiceField

```
choices = (('1', 'some text',),
           ('2', 'some text',),
           ('3', 'some text',))

host = forms.ChoiceField(choices = choices)
```

And a simple CharField

```
hostAdress = forms.CharField()
```

Do you have any ideas to get it this way?

Comment: You need to do this with javascript on the frontend

Answer (score 0):

you can start with the char field disabled/hidden and use javascript to catch change event on the select box and change the charfield on that event. For example:

```
$("#id_choice").change(function(eObj) {
    $("#id_char").removeAttr("disabled");
```

this is just an example (using jQuery), you need to make sure to disable the charfield again if the select box is unselected (not sure if you allow this behaviour) and you also need to handle the display of form errors properly if you hide the field and not enable/disable it.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) for this.

```js
$('your-select-input-selector').change(function() {
    var bDisable = true;
    if ($(this).val() == '3'):
        bDisable = !bDisabled;
    $('your-text-input-selector').prop('disabled', bDisable);
});
```

You also need to handle the case where the select input is already set on the value `3` when you first load the page.

Comment: Looks fine. But i have not much experience in javascript. How can i adress the field names. I've tried '#host' for 'your-select-input-selector' and '#hostAdress' for 'your-text-input-selector', but i won't work

Comment: Follow some newbie jQuery tutorial (so you know the very basics). Then, if you rendered your model form automatically with something like: `{{ form.as_table }}`, Django already took care of giving IDs to your fields. Basically the ID is `id_<field_name>`, even though you can customize them.